# How to use mouse in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, mouse, x86-16

I need to write an assembly code that if you click a particular icon on a screen, a sound is activated.(For example: piano) 
How to do it?

I'm using a **Assembly 86** and dosbox 0.74-3 If that helps.

This is the code that creates the piano (5 white rectangles)
I need that when the mouse clicks on one of the rectangles, it will make a sound.

I know how to make a sound, I just need the sound to be heard when the icons are clicked.
The remarks are in Hebrew because it is my native language

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
; --------------------------
color db 12
Player_CoordinateIn_X dw 5
Player_CoordinateIn_Y dw 10 
Player_CoordinateIn_X1 dw 40
Player_CoordinateIn_X2 dw 75
Player_CoordinateIn_X3 dw 110
Player_CoordinateIn_X4 dw 145
Player_CoordinateIn_X5 dw 180
Player_CoordinateIn_X6 dw 215
Player_CoordinateIn_X7 dw 250

include "iconbox.asm"


; --------------------------
CODESEG
; ---------------------------------------

proc printIcon
 push offset iconbox ;שם האייקון
 push 25d ;Width
 push 150d ;Height
 push 15D ;Color
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_X] ; x location
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_Y] ;y location
 call drawIcon
 ret
endp printIcon

proc drawIcon
;פרוצדורה מקבלת מיקום ותמונה
;פרוצדורה מדפיסה תמונה במיקום המבוקש
iconOffset EQU [BP+14] ;מספר האייקון
iconWidth EQU [BP+12] ;רוחב האייקון
iconHeight EQU [BP+10] ;גובה האייקון
iconColor EQU [BP+8] ;צבע האייקון
iconX EQU [BP+6] ;מיקום ציר X
iconY EQU [BP+4] ;מיקום ציר Y

 add [bp],10
 push bp
 mov bp,sp
 ;PushAll
 mov si,0
 mov di,0
 mov bx,iconOffset
 mov dx,iconY
bigLoop: 
 cmp [byte ptr bx],0
 je afterPixel
 MOV AX,iconColor
 MOV AH,0Ch
 MOV CX,iconX
 ADD CX,SI 
 INT 10H
afterPixel:
 inc bx
 inc si
 cmp si,iconWidth
 jne bigLoop
 mov si,0
 inc dx
 inc di
 cmp di,iconHeight
 jne bigLoop
 ;PopAll
 pop bp
 ret 12
endp drawIcon

proc open_grafic
    mov ax,13h
    int 10h
    ret 
endp open_grafic
;------------------------------------
proc printIcon2
 push offset iconbox ;שם האייקון
 push 25d ;Width
 push 150d ;Height
 push 15D ;Color
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_X1] ; x location
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_Y] ;y location
 call drawIcon
 ret
endp printIcon2
;--------------------------------------
proc printIcon1
 push offset iconbox ;שם האייקון
 push 25d ;Width
 push 150d ;Height
 push 15D ;Color
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_X2] ; x location
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_Y] ;y location
 call drawIcon
 ret
endp printIcon1
;--------------------------------------
proc printIcon3
 push offset iconbox ;שם האייקון
 push 25d ;Width
 push 150d ;Height
 push 15D ;Color
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_X3] ; x location
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_Y] ;y location
 call drawIcon
 ret
endp printIcon3
;--------------------------------------
proc printIcon4
 push offset iconbox ;שם האייקון
 push 25d ;Width
 push 150d ;Height
 push 15D ;Color
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_X4] ; x location
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_Y] ;y location
 call drawIcon
 ret
endp printIcon4
;--------------------------------------
proc printIcon5
 push offset iconbox ;שם האייקון
 push 25d ;Width
 push 150d ;Height
 push 15D ;Color
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_X5] ; x location
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_Y] ;y location
 call drawIcon
 ret
endp printIcon5
;--------------------------------------
proc printIcon6
 push offset iconbox ;שם האייקון
 push 25d ;Width
 push 150d ;Height
 push 15D ;Color
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_X6] ; x location
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_Y] ;y location
 call drawIcon
 ret
endp printIcon6
;--------------------------------------
proc printIcon7
 push offset iconbox ;שם האייקון
 push 25d ;Width
 push 150d ;Height
 push 15D ;Color
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_X7] ; x location
 push [Player_CoordinateIn_Y] ;y location
 call drawIcon
 ret
endp printIcon7
;--------------------------------------
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
; -------------------------
call open_grafic
call printIcon
call printIcon1
call printIcon2
call printIcon3
call printIcon4
call printIcon5
call printIcon6
call printIcon7
    ; --------------------------
    mov ax,0h
int 33h
; Show mouse
mov ax,1h
int 33h
; Loop until mouse click
MouseLP :
mov ax,3h
int 33h
cmp bx, 01h ; check left mouse click
jne MouseLP
; Print dot near mouse location
shr cx,1 ; adjust cx to range 0-319, to fit screen
sub dx, 1 ; move one pixel, so the pixel will not be hidden by mouse
mov bh,0h
mov al,[color]
mov ah,0Ch
int 10h
; Press any key to continue
mov ah,00h
 int 16h
; Text mode
mov ax,3h
int 10h



exit:

end start
```

Comment: Assembly for which processor?  Running what operating system?  Do you already have an application that shows an icon with a piano that you want to click?  What have you tried?  [No attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), [No code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/), [No research.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Comment: Hello eliotz, Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Most importantly, can you debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already waits for a left button click:

```
MouseLP:
    mov     ax, 0003h   ; MOUSE.GetMousePosition
    int     33h         ; -> BX CX DX
    test    bx, 1       ; Is left button down?
    jz      MouseLP     ; No
    shr     cx, 1       ; Adjust cx to range 0-319, to fit screen
```

Once the click arrives you start comparing the coordinates that you got in `CX` (X) and `DX` (Y) with the coordinates of the rectangle that interests you:

All of your rectangles have the same width (25) and height (150).
Next snippet will check if the mouse was clicked while above your first rectangle, whose upperleft corner is at (Player_CoordinateIn_X1, Player_CoordinateIn_Y).

```
    mov     ax, [Player_CoordinateIn_X1]  ; UpperLeftCornerX
    cmp     cx, ax
    jb      Outside
    add     ax, 25-1                      ; LowerRightCornerX
    cmp     cx, ax
    ja      Outside
    mov     ax, [Player_CoordinateIn_Y]   ; UpperLeftCornerY
    cmp     dx, ax
    jb      Outside
    add     ax, 150-1                     ; LowerRightCornerY
    cmp     dx, ax
    ja      Outside
Inside:
    ... Make the corresponding sound!
Outside:
    ... Go check for another mouse click!
```

---

> ```
> proc drawIcon
>  add [bp],10
>  push bp
>  mov bp,sp
> ```

Your *drawIcon* proc starts with this strange instruction `add [bp],10`. What's it supposed to do?